# I just downloaded ubuntu, but I cannot change the directory to "/C" or similar

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just downloaded ubuntu.
I can't change the directory. I try to type `cd /C` or `cd ~/C /Users` or `cd /c`, but it just doesn't work.
I use `pwd` to check the current directory,  which is `/home/simon`.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that a path "/C" exists?

Comment: Try `cd /` followed by `ls`.

Comment: Are you referring to Windows Subsystem for Linux, and trying to find your disks that you are used to on your Windows? Possibly relevant: [your C: drive is at `/mnt/c`](https://superuser.com/questions/1107618/where-is-the-c-drive-in-the-wsl)

Comment: You're not on Windows any more Dorothy

Comment: @Amadan Good alternative angle. Are you making an answer or is it OK if I extend mine to also cover it?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Sure, extend away.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me for assuming that by `/C` you mean "root of the file system".
It is an expectation/assumption which can easily be caused by spending much time with a different widely spread operating system.

If what you are actually looking for is the root of the filesystem, then use

```
cd /
```

In order to see the content of the filesystem root, then continue by using

```
ls
```

Or, too see the content of the root without actually changing the current working directory, use

```
ls /
```

Alternatively (credits to Amadan), if you are looking for the content of your windows drives, check

```
/mnt/c
```

and have a look at the explanations found here
https://superuser.com/questions/1107618/where-is-the-c-drive-in-the-wsl

Answer (score 1):

There's no C: in Linux. The `/` or `root` is in the top of the directory hierarchy. Go to root using `cd /` and use `ls` command to list all the files and folder in the root. You can keep navigating from there using the cd and ls. Users & Documents equivalent in Linux is the `home` folder. I recommend studying more about the [Linux file system](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/)

Comment: thank you for providing that website. i now know more about the Linux